# My mySQL server is displaying dates in american format

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to make my mysql and php server automatically display dates in UK format.

At the moment I run a function to convert them.

the way the data is stored in the database 2012/06/20 the way i want the server to store it 20/06/2012

--------------Update------------------
//SQL_data comes from the table

echo $sql_date; // 2012/06/20

then i use this to swap the dates around.

```
function fixdate($in_date) {
    $split_data = explode('-', $in_date);
    if(count($split_data) == 3) {
        $year = $split_data[2]; $month = $split_data[1]; $day = $split_data[0];
        return "$year-$month-$day";
     } else {
        return FALSE;
     }
}
```

then i display the date.

then i use the function again to store it in the database because it does not accept any other format.

My question is: is there a way that I can just set the default mysql date formate to UK standers.

hope i have explained it better this time.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? How you retrieve the dates, how you display them, what you get as a result?

Comment: If by "function" you mean "php function" then lookie here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: disregard negative votes by basement dwellers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can use the date() and strtotime() functions to convert date to whatever format you want. E.g. for DD-MM-YYYY

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_from_db))
```

Comment: This is what i do all ready but what i wanted todo is...
If I return a date from the database it already be in the correct format.

Comment: @Stephen Wolfe: you haven't replied to my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117695/my-mysql-server-is-displaying-dates-in-american-format/11117732#comment14565586_11117695. Without it - it is impossible to help you

Comment: MySQL stores a date as YYYY-MM-DD http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html At best, you can use date_format() in your SQL or manipulate the returned date in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setlocale.php) function in PHP. For MySQL try to change locale with [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locale-support.html)

Comment: Can I view example of the string you have?

Comment: I'm not an OP, and it is not an answer, it is just a random guess (wrong one)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can set mysql to accept unauthorised dates and is strongly not recommended.

So I will have to format the date on retrieving the dates from the data base and inserting them.

```
DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

my example

```
public function customerList()
    {
        return $this->db->select("
            SELECT
            _payments.id,
            _payments.dueDate,
            _payments.paymentMethod,
            _payments.paymentAmount,
            DATE_FORMAT(_payments.paidDate,'%d/%m/%Y') as paidDate,
            _payments.custId,
            _customers.firstname,
            _customers.lastname,
            _customers.advisor
            FROM
            _payments
            Inner Join _customers ON _payments.custId = _customers.id
            WHERE _payments.paid = 0
        ");
    }
```